# React: Can/should I use a custom hooks instead of HOC even if there's no state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got an existing app which uses Higher Order Components in React. I gather you can move on/improve HOC by using render props, however now with React custom hooks out I gather that may be the best approach.

When reading the React docs, all the custom hook examples use state in their examples. Can/should I use a custom hook to replace a HOC where state is not being used? If so can anyone point me to an example please?

Answer (score 5):

> Can/should I use a custom hook to replace a HOC where state is not being used?

Disadvantage of having an HOC is because of [wrapper hell](https://medium.com/@jackyef/react-hooks-why-we-should-embrace-it-86e408663ad6).

If there's no state, you can treat it as a **pure function component**. Then there **won't be any need of hooks** as well.

Hooks is only made to add a stateful logic and lifecycle to function components.

Maybe all you need is just [Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). :)

Comment: Agree with @Joseph D. If your component does not even use state. There is no reason of adding hooks. Making it stateless function component may be the best thing with minimal refactor. Are you doing it because you foresee that state might need to be injected in the current stateless component ?